# How to find out how many specific data is in mysql data?

Tags: mysql

There are columns called'member_id' and'board' in the table called'table_rating'.

When there is data as shown below, I want to get the total number of AAA, BBB, and CCC of test001 members.

| member_id | board |
| --- | --- |
| soria | AAA |
| tosom | BBB |
| test001 | AAA |
| david | CCC |
| test001 | CCC |
| test001 | AAA |
| jessi | DDD |
| test001 | DDD |

The query I tried is below.
The result is only the sum of each.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN board='AAA' THEN 1 END) AS cnt,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN board='BBB' THEN 1 END) AS cnt,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN board='CCC' THEN 1 END) AS cnt
FROM `table_rating` WHERE member_id = 'test001';
```

| cnt | cnt | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

Can't we combine cnt values into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `WHERE` clause restricting to only board types of `AAA`, `BBB`, and `CCC`, and then add `COUNT(*)` for the total count:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(board = 'AAA') AS a_cnt,
    SUM(board = 'BBB') AS b_cnt,
    SUM(board = 'CCC') AS c_cnt,
    COUNT(*) AS total_cnt
FROM table_rating
WHERE
    member_id = 'test001' AND
    board IN ('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC');
```

Note that I am taking advantage of MySQL's ability to sum boolean expressions here for a more terse syntax.